# MySQL Replication Query

Tags: replication, update, mysql-5.6

Imagine I have three servers.
x.x.x.31 - master
x.x.x.32 - slave
x.x.x.33 - slave

If I run a simple update in master. What does the slave servers done. run the update command or copy the updated data from master?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the replication configuration. The two [Replication Formats](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-formats.html) are Statement-based Replication and Row-Based Replication.

The default is `Statement-Based` logging.

If the [Statement-Based Replication](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-sbr-rbr.html#replication-sbr-rbr-sbr-advantages) is used, the master writes SQL statements to the binary log and the SQL statements are executed on the slave.

In the case of [Row-Based Replcation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-sbr-rbr.html#replication-sbr-rbr-rbr-advantages), the master writes events to the binary log that indicate how individual tables rows are changed. These events are then copied to the slave.

Another format is [Mixed-Based Replication](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/binary-log-mixed.html). MySQL replication can also be configured to use a mix of both Statement and Row-Based logging. Statement-based log is used by default, but depending on certain statements, the log is automatically changed to row-based.

Refer to [binlog_format](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-options-binary-log.html#sysvar_binlog_format), to configure the logging format and for [binary log setting](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/binary-log-setting.html) more information.